# How to locate host storage for backups by interpretting volumes in docker-compose.yml?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, database-backups

I'm hoping to locate the data in the host storage by interpreting this docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mariadb
    container_name: nextcloud-mariadb
    command: --transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED --binlog-format=ROW
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD={password}
      - MYSQL_DATABASE={database}
      - MYSQL_USER={user}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD={password}
    env_file:
      - db.env
    networks:
      - nextcloud-proxy-tier

  app:
    image: nextcloud:fpm-alpine
    container_name: nextcloud-app
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - nextcloud:/var/www/html
    environment:
      - MYSQL_HOST=db
    env_file:
      - db.env
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - nextcloud-proxy-tier

  web:
    build: ./web
    container_name: nextcloud-web
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - nextcloud:/var/www/html:ro
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST={fqdn.url}
    depends_on:
      - app
    networks:
      - nextcloud-proxy-tier
      - default

  proxy:
    build: ./proxy
    container_name: nextcloud-proxy
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 8880:80
    volumes:
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
      - vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    networks:
      - nextcloud-proxy-tier
    depends_on:
      - omgwtfssl

  omgwtfssl:
    image: paulczar/omgwtfssl
    container_name: nextcloud-ssl-cert-gen
    restart: "no"
    volumes:
      - certs:/certs
    environment:
      - SSL_SUBJECT=servhostname.local
      - CA_SUBJECT={me@ema.il}
      - SSL_KEY=/certs/servhostname.local.key
      - SSL_CSR=/certs/servhostname.local.csr
      - SSL_CERT=/certs/servhostname.local.crt
    networks:
      - nextcloud-proxy-tier

volumes:
  db:
  nextcloud:
  certs:
  vhost.d:
  html:

networks:
  nextcloud-proxy-tier:
```

CURRENT GOALS:
1) learn how to make sense of the `db:/var/lib/mysql` syntax
2) learn whether this structure lends itself more toward one particular backup solution or another.

My overall goal is to set up automated backups, but I've been away from the project long enough that I'm struggling to remember what my plans were (why things were structured the way they are), and unable to find the tutorials I was following (this is my first Docker project ever).

My notes are clear on my intended backup strategy:
`docker commit -p {container_id} {target_name}`, and then
`docker save {repo_img_name} > {target_name.tar}`, then
use Duply & Duplicity to store offsite copies.  (note: Duply is 99% set up, and ready to test) 
Unfortunately, based on today's Googling, the data in the MariaDB wouldn't be included in the image created by `commit`.

My memory is that the MariaDB is using a volume to make the data more accessible and easier to backup. Most of the recommendations I'm finding today are recommending an additional container for taking the MySQL backups, but I'm pretty sure the solution prescribed in one of the tute's I was following was much more simple/direct than this.  I feel like I've been going in circles on this all day.

Answer (score 0):

The only important things to back up in a typical Docker setup are the contents of the volumes.  The containers themselves are meant to be deleted and recreated from their respective images.  You don't need to use `docker commit` here (or pretty much ever).

The Docker documentation has [a section on backing up named volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes).  The essential approach here is that you need to run another container mounting these volumes to get access to the data.  Docker Compose generally names things by adding a "project name" (by default the current directory name) as a prefix, so you could run something like

```
docker run \
  -v project_db:/mnt/db \
  -v project_nextcloud:/mnt/nextcloud \
  ...
  -v $PWD:/backup \
  -w /mnt \
  busybox \
  tar cf /backup/volumes.tar db nextcloud ...
```

If you're willing to break Docker's abstractions and you're not using a non-default volume storage driver, you can also [`docker volume inspect`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_inspect/) each of these volumes, and its output will include the host path where it actually lives.  Named volumes will tend to have a stable path.  This is, technically, implementation details, and Docker could in principle change it in a future release.

The lazy, will-probably-work path here is to point your backup software at `/var/lib/docker/volumes`.

Whatever backup strategy you pick, make sure you practice restoring it.  For the project you show just doing it on the same system in a virtual machine is probably an easy path.  My suspicion is that you will need to run [`docker-compose up --no-start`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/) to get it to create the volumes, and then restore the backup into the correct paths (there is metadata elsewhere that records that the volume exists).